# Is it possible to open an interactive pane or window with Visual Studio Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create an (ideally) all-in-one cross platform tile based map/sprite/image editor for a game engine, since the current official one is Windows only and doesn't play nicely with WINE/Mono. Instead of building one from scratch, I figured it might be easier to create an extension for Visual Studio Code, but side panes don't seem to be interactive, and I'm having trouble getting it to open an electron window.

Is this possible, or should I just build it from scratch with electron?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work. Visual Studio Code is a code editor, which supports extensions that can either add functionality to the IDE itself or provide HTML content to show in an own pane. This is not enough (and not made) for a full featured editor-in-editor scenario (interaction is limited).

[I've built an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4) which has a graphical view of a graph (see the last image) using D3.js, with limited interaction capabilities (you can select/drag a node and pan/zoom with the mouse).

Better is probably to go level down and start with Electron (on which vscode is based). This would allow you to write any desktop application that can be written in HTML/JS.

Comment: Alright. To avoid having to completely reinvent the wheel, do you think building a separate app with electron, compiling it to a executable program, and then packaging that program with the extension and calling it with child_process.exec(...) would be a reasonable solution?

Comment: Yes, sounds reasonable.